# Como realizar operaciones matematicas con los valores de un array

Tags: array, bucle-for, function, foreach

Tengo un problema al restar los valores de un array entre si. La suma funciona perfectamente, pero la resta no. Siempre me hace números negativos, y no seria el caso.

Este es mi código:

```
var numbers = [];

var userTimes = prompt('Cuantas operaciones quieres hacer?')

for (var i=0; i<userTimes; i++) {
    var user = parseInt(prompt('Escribe un valor'));
    numbers.push(user);
    console.log(numbers);
}

function sum() {
    var acc = 0;
    numbers.forEach(function(obj){
        acc += obj;
    })
    return acc;
}
console.log('La suma entre ' + numbers + ' hace: ' + sum());

function subs() {
    var acc = 0;
    numbers.forEach(function(obj){
        acc -= obj;
    })
    return acc;
}
console.log('La resta entre ' + numbers + ' hace: ' + subs());

//Output sum: La suma entre 8,5,1 hace: 14
//Output subs: La resta entre 8,5,1 hace: -14
```

Comment: si empieza desde cero siempre va a dar negativo, salvo que restes un negativo ej: `0 - 4 = -4`, `-4 - (-8) = 4`, `0 - (-4) = 4`

Comment: Estoy reproduciendo tu caso y para los valores que comentas da suma:14 y resta: -14. Es lógico que ese resultado en la resta por lo que @aloMalbarez te ha explicado en el comentario de arriba. No entiendo como te ha dado -6 no hay forma posible si los valores son: 8, 5 y 1 como has mencionado

Comment: Otra cosa, no indicas que quieres restar con que, es decir, si son 3 números que deseas que haga la resta? 8-5-1? -8-5-1? quieres que siempre el primero sea positivo para realizar una suma algebraica?

Comment: Si, quiero que siempre sea 8-5-1, pero claro, no se como hacerlo, ya que con la suma voy acumulando y perfecto, pero con la resta veo que restándole el acumulador, siempre van a ser negativos. aloMalbarez y tu @Huskie, tenéis toda la razón del mundo, pero otra cosa es saberlo hacer...  Lo mismo me pasa con la multiplicación y la división. Estoy prácticamente empezando en este mundo, y me está costando bastante asimilar las cosas.

Comment: Ok. ya te coloco la respuesta. Supuse que eso era lo que querías y ya tengo la respuesta. Pruebala y por favor me dices

Comment: a mi me salio -6 la resta cuando le pifie al 8 (el parseint hizo que la u se transforme en cero) ... `0 - 5 - 1 = -6` =S

Comment: Habia un error en el código original que hacia que el output de la resta fuera -6. Luego al arreglaro, me he olvidado de cambiar el output tambien. Por eso era un poco confuso.

Comment: @aloMalbarez xD!

Comment: @jaumeserr tranquilo, estamos en esta comunidad justo para eso, para aprender. Yo porque tenía la duda, estaba probando tu código y decía: "no entiendo como le dió 6" jaja. Si se te dificulta la multiplicación y la división has otra pregunta y haremos los posible por colaborarte. Un saludo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

he revisado el código y ya que estas empezando creo que te será mucho mas fácil de la siguiente manera:

```
var numbers = [];

function askNumsToCalculate() {

    var userTimes = prompt('Cuantas operaciones quieres hacer?')

    for (var i=0; i<userTimes; i++) {
        var user = parseInt(prompt('Escribe un valor'));
        numbers.push(user);
    }

    if(numbers.length === 1) {
        console.log('La raíz cuadrada de ' + numbers[0] + ' es: ' + Math.sqrt(numbers[0]).toFixed(3));

    } else if(numbers.length === 2) {
        operationsNums();
    }
}

askNumsToCalculate();


function operationsNums() {

    function resta() {

        var result = [];

        if(result.length === 0) {
            result.push(numbers[0]);    
        }

        for (var j=1; j<numbers.length; j++) {
            var resta = result[0] - numbers[j];
            result = []
            result.push(resta)
        }
        console.log(result);
    }

    resta();
operationsNums();
```

Si tienes alguna duda sobre el código, te contestare encantado.

Answer (score 1):

Aclarado lo que necesitas por los comentarios que dejas en la descripción de tu pregunta. El error que tienes es que básicamente siempre transformas el primer número en negativo por la lógica que utilizaste en tu código. Para lograr una correcta suma algebraica debes agregar una condición que te permita capturar el primer número y sumarlo en vez de restarlo para poder realizar la operación correctamente.

Como estás empezando a programar no simplificaré ni complicaré (para optimizar tu trabajo) el código sino que colocaré aquel que es más didáctico y soluciona tu problema simultáneamente. A continuación la corrección a tu código:

```js
var numbers = [];
var cont=1;

var userTimes = prompt('Cuantas operaciones quieres hacer?')

for (var i=0; i<userTimes; i++) {
    var user = parseInt(prompt('Escribe un valor'));
    numbers.push(user);
    console.log(numbers);
}

function sum() {
    var acc = 0;
    numbers.forEach(function(obj){
        acc += obj;
    })
    return acc;
}
console.log('La suma entre ' + numbers + ' hace: ' + sum());

function subs() {
    var acc = 0;
    numbers.forEach(function(obj){
     if(cont==1){
        acc += obj;
        cont++;
      }
      else{
       acc -= obj;
      }
    })
    return acc;
}
console.log('La resta entre ' + numbers + ' hace: ' + subs());

//Output sum: La suma entre 8,5,1 hace: 14
//Output subs: La resta entre 8,5,1 hace: -6
```

Espero sea de ayuda. Un saludo!

Comment: Súper bien explicado y entendible @Huskie. Mil gracias!

Comment: De nada, me alegra que fue útil. Un saludo!

Answer (score 1):

Tu código se puede simplificar/*reducir* bastante, mediante el uso de [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/reduce).

En el caso de la suma, este método se encargará de sumar todos los elementos del array. En el caso de la resta, usaremos un ternario, diciéndole que, cuando sea el primer elemento no haga ninguna operación. Esto dejará intacto el primer valor y restará todos los que vengan a continuación... Así de sencillo.

He añadido otro elemento al código: control de los prompt, para que el usuario no introduzca números negativos en el primer caso, y para que sólo introduzca números en el segundo caso.

Espero te sirva.

```js
do {
  var userTimes = parseInt(prompt("¿Cuántas operaciones quieres hacer?", ""), 10);
} while (isNaN(userTimes) || userTimes < 1);

var numbers = [];

for (var i = 0; i < userTimes; i++) {
  do {
    var user = parseInt(prompt("Escribe un valor", ""), 10);
  } while (isNaN(user));

  numbers.push(user);
}



console.log("La suma  es: " + add(numbers));
console.log("La resta es: " + sub(numbers));

/*Función para sumar*/
function add(arrNumbers) {
  var resultado = arrNumbers.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a + b;
  });
  return resultado;
}

/*Función para restar*/
function sub(arrNumbers) {
  var resultado = arrNumbers.reduce(function(a, b, i) {
    /*Restará sólo después del 1er elemento*/
    return (i >= 1) ? a - b : 0;
  });
  return resultado;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por el aporte @A.Cedano. Está claro que el código se puede reducir muchísimo, pero como estoy prácticamente empezando en este mundillo, pues hay muchísimas cosas que aún no tengo asimiladas. Me miraré tu código para intentar entender todo pero como te comento estoy con las bases de momento pero te agradezco muchísimo tu aporte. Muchas gracias!

Comment: @jaumeserr de nada, estamos para colaborar. Puse me respuesta como un aporte adicional, manejando funciones que existen en JS y que simplifican sobremanera operaciones que en el pasado era más complejas. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la funcion [Reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/reduce)

```js
var numbers = [];
var cont=1;
var userTimes = prompt('Cuantas operaciones quieres hacer?')

for (var i=0; i<userTimes; i++) {
    var user = parseInt(prompt('Escribe un valor'));
    numbers.push(user);
}
function sumar(a , b){
  return a + b;
}
function restar(a , b){
  return a - b; 
}
function dividir(a , b){
  return a / b; 
}
function multiplicar(a , b){
  return a * b; 
}
var acciones = [sumar, restar, dividir, multiplicar];

for (let i = 0 ; i <= acciones.length -1 ; i++){
console.log(acciones[i].name +' '  + numbers.toString() + ' =' + numbers.reduce(acciones[i]));
}
```